# 2000 Suzuki Katana 600 starting

Tags: battery, starting, suzuki, katana

So I just purchased a 2000 Suzuki Katana 600. The bike cranks but doesn't want to start. I had the battery tested and it was good. I can get it started with some starter fluid. Then if I go ride it or it sits for any amount of time I have the same issue. It cranks over but it sounds like it's really struggling to do so then after continuously trying it stops cranking. So it sounds like a battery but was told it was good. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Always start with the basics.  To run an gasoline internal combustion engine requires:

1. Fuel
2. Air
3. Compression
4. Ignition

First of all this bike has carburetors and these can be very sensitive to storage especially with ethanol-laced fuels.  From your description that it starts on starter fluid indicate problems with fueling.  You'll probably want to rebuild the carbs to resolve this issue.  There are some in-fuel carb cleaning products but I've had little success with any of them.  But they are relatively inexpensive and easy to use so it's probably worth a try.  Also check that the choke or cold-start enriching circuit and its control is working properly.

Check your airbox and air cleaner to be sure nothing has built a nest in there and the filter is clean.

A compression test is simple enough to do and will give you an indication of the health of the piston rings and valves.  These types of engines will run on 3 out of 4 cylinders but not well and can be difficult to start.

It sounds like your ignition, i.e. spark plugs and coils are working OK.  So I'd leave those go for now.